# KnockoutJS - Correct Way of Writing KO BindingHandlers for Input Type Radio

Tags: javascript, html, web, knockout.js

I have set a custom binding for input type radio, which is like this:

```
"radio-yesno": function(bindingContext, dataClasses){
    return {
        click: this,
    }
},
```

The Html Input Type Radio binds to this is written like this:

```
<label class="radio inline">
   <input type="radio" name="RadioTest" id="RadioYes" data-class="radio-yesno"/>
   Yes
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
   <input type="radio" name="RadioTest" id="RadioNo" data-class="radio-yesno"/>
   No
</label>
```

(You may notice that I am using data-class here to bind the element, it is because I am using the **ClassBindingProvider** plugin)

The problem now is when the radio button is clicked, the **function which contains the associated observable of this element is actually triggered** and during debugging it can be seen that the value of

```
$('#RadioNo').is(':checked')
```

is actually true when the No Radio Button is clicked and is false when the Yes Radio Button is clicked. **BUT, the page itself doesn't show the Radio Button to be selected (checked).**

Currently the ko BindingHandlers that I am using here is "click" only.

I have tried to add more bindingHandler which is "checked: this" and put it below the "click: this" line, but still doesn't work.

Could someone please help me to identify what is the problem here and how should it be fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question exactly what you want the behavior to be, but I've put together a snippet with typical radio button behavior. The most important change is that I added a `value` attribute to each radio button element. Without them, there's no value change on selecting a different radio button.

I have written but commented out a click binding here, and am using a checked binding, which is usually the better way to bind a radio group. I subscribe to the bound variable just to output information when it changes.

```js
let bindings = {
  "radio-yesno": function(bindingContext, dataClasses) {
    return {
      // click: this.clickHandler,
      checked: this.checkedVariable
    }
  }
};
ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.classBindingProvider(bindings);
let vm = {
  clickHandler: function(data, event) {
    console.debug("Click:", data, event);
    true;
  },
  checkedVariable: ko.observable('on')
};

vm.checkedVariable.subscribe((newValue) => {
  console.debug('New value:', newValue);
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/rniemeyer/knockout-classBindingProvider/master/src/knockout-classBindingProvider.js"></script>
<label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioTest" value="on" data-class="radio-yesno" />Yes
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioTest" value="off" data-class="radio-yesno" />No
</label>
```